# Unscrambling a string given the number of splits and words that the sentence can be comprised of

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Im working on a problem in which I'm given a string that has been scrambled. The scrambling works like this.

An original string is chopped into substrings at random positions and a random number of times.
Each substring is then moved around randomly to form a new string.

I'm also given a dictionary of words that are possible words in the string.

Finally, i'm given the number of splits in the string that were made.

The example I was given is this:

```
dictionary = ["world", "hello"]
scrambled_string = rldhello wo
splits = 1
```

The expected output of my program would be the original string, in this case:
"hello world"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the initial string

```
"hello my name is Sean"
```

with

```
splits = 2
```

yields

```
["hel", "lo my name ", "is Sean"]
```

and those three pieces are shuffled to form the following array:

```
["lo my name ", "hel", "is Sean"]
```

and then the elements of this array are joined to form:

```
scrambled = "lo my name helis Sean"
```

Also suppose:

```
dictionary = ["hello", "Sean", "the", "name", "of", "my", "cat", "is", "Sugar"]
```

First convert `dictionary` to a set to speed lookups.

```
require 'set'

dict_set = dictionary.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"hello", "Sean", "the", "name", "of", "my", "cat", "is", "Sugar"}>
```

Next I will create a helper method.

```
def indices_to_ranges(indices, last_index)
  [-1, *indices, last_index].each_cons(2).map { |i,j| i+1..j }
end
```

Suppose we split `scrambled` twice (because `splits #=> 2`), specifically after the `'y'` and the `'h'`:

```
indices = [scrambled.index('y'), scrambled.index('h')]
  #=> [4, 11]
```

The first element of `indices` will always be `-1` and the last value will always be `scrambled.size-1`.

We may then use `indices_to_ranges` to convert these indices to ranges of indices of characters in `scrambed`:

```
ranges = indices_to_ranges(indices, scrambled.size-1)
  #=> [0..4, 5..11, 12..20]

a = ranges.map { |r| scrambled[r] }
  #=> ["lo my", " name h", "elis Sean"]
```

We could of course combine these two steps:

```
a = indices_to_ranges(indices, scrambled.size-1).map { |r| scrambled[r] }
  #=> ["lo my", " name h", "elis Sean"]
```

Next I will permute the values of `a`. For each permutation I will join the elements to form a string, then split the string on single spaces to form an array of words. If all of those words are in the dictionary we may claim success and are finished. Otherwise, a different array `indices` will be constructed and we try again, continuing until success is realized or all possible arrays `indices` have been considered. We can put all this in the following method.

```
def unscramble(scrambled, dict_set, splits)
  last_index = scrambled.size-1
  (0..scrambled.size-2).to_a.combination(splits).each do |indices|
    indices_to_ranges(indices, last_index).
    map { |r| scrambled[r] }.
    permutation.each do |arr|
      next if arr[0][0] == ' ' || arr[-1][-1] == ' '
      words = arr.join.split(' ')
      return words if words.all? { |word| dict_set.include?(word) }
    end
  end
end
```

Let's try it.

```
original string: "hello my name is Sean"
scrambled = "lo my name helis Sean"
splits = 4
```

```
unscramble(scrambled, dict_set, splits)
  #=> ["my", "name", "hello", "is", "Sean"]
```

See [Array#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) and [Array#permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation).

Answer (score 1):

bonkers answer (not quite perfect yet ... trouble with single chars):

```
#
# spaces appear to be important!

@check = {}
@ordered = []

def previous_words (word)
  @check.select{|y,z| z[:previous] == word}.map do |nw,z|
    @ordered << nw
    previous_words(nw)
  end
end

def in_word(dictionary, string)
  # check each word in the dictionary to see if the string is container in one of them
  dictionary.each do |word|
    if word.include?(string)
      return word
    end
  end
  return nil
end

letters=scrambled.split("")
previous=nil
substr=""

letters.each do |l|
  if in_word(dictionary, substr+l)
    substr+= l
  elsif (l==" ")
    word=in_word(dictionary, substr)
    @check[word]={found: 1}
    @check[word][:previous] = previous if previous
    substr=""
    previous=word
  else
    word=in_word(dictionary, substr)
    @check[word]={found: 1}
    @check[word][:previous] = previous if previous
    substr=l
    previous=nil
  end
end
word=in_word(dictionary, substr)
@check[word]={found: 1}
@check[word][:previous] = previous if previous

@check.select{|y,z| z[:previous].nil?}.map do |w,z|
  @ordered << w
  previous_words(w)
end

pp @ordered
```

output:

```
dictionary = ["world", "hello"]
scrambled = "rldhello wo"

... my code here ...

2.5.8 :817 > @ordered
 => ["hello", "world"]
```

```
dictionary = ["hello", "my", "name", "is", "Sean"]
scrambled = "me is Shelleano my na"

... my code here ...

2.5.8 :879 > @ordered
 => ["Sean", "hello", "my", "name", "is"]
```